# Modify UIToolBar items programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uitoolbar

I have created a toolbar using Interface Builder. I have a number of buttons in the toolbar that are hooked up to various `IBAction` methods.  What I want to do is, when selecting one item, visually grey out another by changing it's tint.

How can I get a reference to the `BarButtonItem`? I can't see where I can give each label a unique name where so that I can reference it specifically.

**Update**

I created an `IBOutlet` for the tool bar so i now have acces to it. Unfortunately when I try to set the `tintColor` it crashes.  Here is my code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *penButton = [_toolBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UIBarButtonItem *crossButton = [_toolBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

penButton.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
crossButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The error thrown:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem
>   setTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x631df50'

Comment: What iOS version are you testing on?

Comment: Are you sure you are testing on a device or simulator running 5.0 or above? If you run this code on a device below 5.0 it will crash with this exact error.

Comment: Actually no. Despite being targetted at 5 in the build config the simulator was set to 4.3.  Interestingly when I now run my project nothing appears in my main listview (the list appears though) so I cannot actually test that this fixes it!

Comment: thanks but it was actually tomasz's answer that actually answered your question of how to get references to the toolbar items. All I did was reason that since UIBarButtonItems do recognize the selector setTintColor in iOS 5 the logical conclusion was you were not running in iOS 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *items = [myUIToolbar items];
for (UIBarButtonItem *barButton in items) {
   //do something with button
}
```

Comment: How do I give it the name myUIToolbar ? I cant find the option in interface builder!

Comment: Add, in IB, new referencing outlet from your Toolbar to your .h file and name it like you want.

Comment: Just figured that out before you wrote that, still, when I try to change the tint it crashes - I'll update my question

Comment: Please, add crash log to your question

Comment: Your code works for me. Split it into parts: first get UIBarButtomItem to local variable, after this change tint color.

Comment: Tried that but still doesn't work, also I noticed that in Interface Builder I've set the initial tint state of one of the buttons to be `darkGray` but it doesn't actually start in that state?